# How do you always check if user is signed in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, authentication

Ruby on Rails 3.2

My web application has two types of users. I just noticed that one of my folders in View is visible to the public.

How do you make sure users are logged in sitewide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `before_filter` that checks if the user is signed in inside `ApplicationController`. When you do this, all your controllers, all your actions, will be filtered by this condition.

If you are using something like `devise`, you have a custom method named `authenticate_user` that do this kind of stuff for you, so as an example, your code will look like this:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

Comment: I have this for my other controllers, how do you do a before_filter for two filters? before_filter :signed_in_grandstreamer, only: [:edit, :update, :show] AND/OR before_filter :signed_in_distributor,  only: [:edit, :update, :show, :index]. It will error out since they are both not signed in.

Comment: I am not sure if i understand what do you mean by before_filter for two filters.  

The thing is `signed_in_grandstreamer` and `signed_in_distributor` will be called when you perform one of these actions you listed. If you do any action outside these actions, it will not perform the filter and therefore it will not validate. Maybe you need just one generic filter, that checks if it is logged in, if it is a certain kind of user and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can store their id or other details in the Session once they log in and you could check if this Session variable is not null before displaying the view.